# SQLITE find rolling 4 weeks data

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a tble like this in SQLITE . I have to find the sum of previous four weeks sum(Quantity) from that date.

```
Date|Quantity
------|------
4/22/2015|23
4/25/2015|10
5/1/2015| 28
6/9/2015|45
6/29/2015|31
```

Expected result:

```
Date   | Quantity
------ | ------
4/22/2015   | 23
4/25/2015   | 33
5/1/2015    | 38
6/9/2015    | 45
6/29/2015   | 76
```

I am trying with the below query. I am not getting the correct result.

```
select t1.date, t1.quantity, SUM(t2.quantity) as sum
from aaa t1 left join
     aaa t2
     on datetime(t1.date) <= datetime(t2.date, '-28 days')
group by t1.date, t1.quantity
order by t1.date
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are close.  The date comparison needs both a begin and end:

```
select t1.date, t1.quantity, SUM(t2.quantity) as sum
from aaa t1 left join
     aaa t2
     on datetime(t2.date) >= datetime(t1.date, '-28 days') and
        datetime(t2.date) <= datetime(t1.date)
group by t1.date, t1.quantity
order by t1.date;
```